# Why use (open)VPN with (free)radius and not directly with (open)ldap

Tags: networking, ldap, single-sign-on, vpn, radius

For a school project I need to setup a SSO solution.
This includes a vpn service, a postgresql DB and LDAP.
For the VPN solution I need to use OpenVPN but why would I use
Radius (as the documentation/assignment states) when OpenVPN has
a perfectly capable (for as far as I can see) implementation for
OpenLDAP.

So why would I set it up that OpenVPN uses freeRADIUS to ask OpenLDAP
for authentication/authorization?

The network setup:

- Router (eth0 = outside, eth1 = DMZ, eth2 = proxy, tun0 = openvpn = own subnet)
- DMZ (webserver for everything coming from the outside, NGINX and wildlfy)
- Proxy (NGINX, bit redundent i know, eth0 = router, eth1 = internal servers)
- DB server (eth0 = proxy, runs postgresql)
- auth server (eth0 = proxy, runs OpenLDAP)
- snmp server (eth0 = proxy, openNMS, just an added bonus not of interest to the assignment really)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Open VPN expert, but if you want only to check the users credentials and groups privileges you can bypass RADIUS (but I found it and advanced step not only for the auth, also for future use like wifi 802.1X access etc...)